# Job scheduling in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have an MVC application, and try to start a thread to running job scheduling. I use Application_Start in Global.asax to start the thread, and Application_End to stop the thread again.

But some times when the websites has visitors, and i deploy a new version, the Application_Start is fired more than once.

In Global.asax on Application_Start i do this:

```
 BatchClient.Start();
```

And here some of my BatchClient code:

```
public static class BatchClient
{
    public static readonly List<BatchTask> BatchTaskList = new List<BatchTask>();
    public static bool AllowToRun = true;

    private static Thread handleThread = null;

    public static void Start()
    {
        if (handleThread == null)
        {
            AddToInstanceLog("Start - in progress");

            Setup();

            handleThread = new Thread(Handler);
            handleThread.Name = "NextBatchClient.Handler";
            handleThread.Start();

            ThreadUtil.AddThread(handleThread);

            AddToInstanceLog("Start - done");
        }
        else
        {
            AddToInstanceLog("Allready running");
        }
    }
}
```

My unless the Application_Start is call more than once, the handleThread is null every time, so its just start a new thread - and then my jobs are running multiple times.

What to do? :-)

Comment: redesign your application. you should not use the app-pool for batch activites. windows has services and scheduler for this kind of operations.

Comment: If you cannot add a scheduler, use a windows service (with for example [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) as scheduling library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at solutions that are designed for this? Why re-invent the wheel?

Take a look at [Hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io)

You can then just do the following:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(BatchClient.Start(););
```

Or you can add a Recurring job:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => BatchClient.Start(), Cron.Daily);
```

Answer (score 2):

Redesign your application. you should not use the app-pool for batch activites. windows has services and scheduler for this kind of operations.

And here are the number one reasons why should not have background jobs in the app pool. The app pool recycles, and it is not created for hosting batchjobs, Recyle means that it stops the process and starts again. All threads running within the process will be killed. It has some protection against sudden death of your request threads, but nothing for any of the kind you have made.

Suggestions how you can solve it instead.

- Use a service application.
- Use a scheduled task
- use a Azure webjob wich you can schedule

Comment: Recycling will not kill the process. All current processing will be handled, all new processing will be done in a new worker process. (And the old one will stop after all processing is done.)

Comment: the recycling waits for some time and then it the thread is for sure killed, it does not let you finish a background job, the mechanism for waiting is only for requests.